# How do I recover a set from a string?

Tags: python, set

In order to write a set `given_set` to a file, I converted it to a string with `str(given_set)`.  When I read the file to a variable, how do I convert the string back into the set?

Comment: In general `str` conversions are not reversible. `repr` might already be better, but for this you should really use an actual serialization format, for example pickle or JSON. What type of items are in the set?

Comment: strings.  example = `{'first entry', 'bob, hob, rob', 'something else'}`

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` may work if you only have basic types in the set.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  That's what I was looking for.  So I need to export it differently.  Just out of curiosity, what if it was exported with str?